# H5Tget_member_type() return strange values for compound HDF5 data types

Tags: c++, hdf5

I try to decide whether two compound HDF5 data types are equivalent by using the functions  `H5Tget_nmembers()`, `H5Tget_member_name()`, `H5Tget_member_offset()`, `H5Tget_member_class()` and `H5Tget_member_type()`.

The first four functions work as expected, but `H5Tget_member_type()` return strange values.

This code fragment

```
struct Agent0 {
    int      m_iInt1;
    int      m_iInt2;
} ta0;

hid_t hAgentDataType = H5Tcreate (H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(ta0));
H5Tinsert(hAgentDataType, "my_int1",       qoffsetof(ta0, m_iInt1),    H5T_NATIVE_INT);
H5Tinsert(hAgentDataType, "my_int2",       qoffsetof(ta0, m_iInt2),    H5T_NATIVE_INT);

printf("type   of member %d: %ld\n",  0, H5Tget_member_type(hAgentDataType, 0));
printf("type   of member %d: %ld\n",  1, H5Tget_member_type(hAgentDataType, 1));
printf("H5T_NATIVE_INT:     %ld\n", H5T_NATIVE_INT);
```

gives the following output:

```
type   of member 0: 216172782113784122
type   of member 1: 216172782113784123
H5T_NATIVE_INT:     216172782113783820
```

So even though members 0 and 1 are both integers, they have different type values. And both of these values are different to the value of `H5T_NATIVE_INT`. I expected all 3 values to be equal...

So what does `H5Tget_member_type()` really return?

How can i actually compare the data types of members of a compound data type?

EDIT: what's even weirder: if i call H5Tget_meber_type() two time for the same member, i get different values:

```
printf("call #1 for member %d: %016lx\n",  0, H5Tget_member_type(hAgentDataType, 0));
printf("call #2 for member %d: %016lx\n",  0, H5Tget_member_type(hAgentDataType, 0));
```

yields

```
call #1 for member 0: 0300000000000151
call #2 for member 0: 0300000000000152
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to a specific library, take a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it can alleviate you from the low-level details of handling HDF5 compound datasets/attributes. Using HDFql in C++, your issue can be solved as follows:

```
int equivalent(const std::string &compound1, const std::string &compound2)
{

    // declare variables
    HDFql::Cursor cursor;
    char script[1024];
    int i;


    // get name of members of compound1
    sprintf(script, "SHOW MEMBER %s", compound1);
    HDFql::execute(script);


    // get name of members of compound2
    HDFql::cursorUse(&cursor);
    sprintf(script, "SHOW MEMBER %s", compound2);
    HDFql::execute(script);


    if (HDFql::cursorGetCount() != HDFql::cursorGetCount(&cursor))
    {
        return -1;   // number of members of compound1 differs from number of members of compound2
    }


    // compare name of members of compound1 with name of members of compound2
    for(i = 0; i < HDFql::cursorGetCount(); i++)
    {
        HDFql::cursorNext();
        HDFql::cursorNext(&cursor);
        if (strcmp(HDFql::cursorGetChar(), HDFql::cursorGetChar(&cursor)) != 0)
        {
            return -1;   // name of member of compound1 differs from name of member of compound2
        }
    }


    // get data type of members of compound1
    HDFql::cursorUseDefault();
    sprintf(script, "SHOW DATA TYPE %s/", compound1);
    HDFql::execute(script);


    // get data type of members of compound2
    HDFql::cursorUse(&cursor);
    sprintf(script, "SHOW DATA TYPE %s/", compound2);
    HDFql::execute(script);


    // compare data type of members of compound1 with data type of members of compound2
    for(i = 0; i < HDFql::cursorGetCount(); i++)
    {
        HDFql::cursorNext();
        HDFql::cursorNext(&cursor);
        if (*HDFql::cursorGetInt() != *HDFql::cursorGetInt(&cursor))
        {
            return -1;   // data type of member of compound1 differs from data type of member of compound2
        }
    }


    // get offset of members of compound1
    HDFql::cursorUseDefault();
    sprintf(script, "SHOW OFFSET %s", compound1);
    HDFql::execute(script);


    // get offset of members of compound2
    HDFql::cursorUse(&cursor);
    sprintf(script, "SHOW OFFSET %s", compound2);
    HDFql::execute(script);


    // compare offset of members of compound1 with offset of members of compound2
    for(i = 0; i < HDFql::cursorGetCount(); i++)
    {
        HDFql::cursorNext();
        HDFql::cursorNext(&cursor);
        if (*HDFql::cursorGetInt() != *HDFql::cursorGetInt(&cursor))
        {
            return -1;   // offset of member of compound1 differs from offset of member of compound2
        }
    }


    return 0;   // compound1 is equivalent to compound2

}
```

Additional details and examples on how to use HDFql may be found in the [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf).